# Is it allowed to "copy" an API database?

Tags: database, api

I'm in need of a certain web API, but the ones have found have rate limits that won't be enough for me.

I can set up my own database and store the results that I get from the API, to reduce the amount of calls. This will eventually lead to a point where I, more or less, have copied the API database.

Is this okay? It might be morally questionable, but is there anything that actually prevents me from doing it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the terms of service of the API vendor.

ex: google maps

> 10.1 Restrictions on How You May Use the Maps API(s). Except as explicitly
>   permitted in Section 8 (Licenses from
>   Google to You) or the Maps APIs
>   Documentation, you must not (nor may
>   you permit anyone else to) do any of
>   the following:
>
> 10.1.3 Restrictions against Data Export or Copying.
>
> (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or
>   Storage of Content. You must not
>   pre-fetch, cache, or store any
>   Content, except that you may store:
>   (i) limited amounts of Content for the
>   purpose of improving the performance
>   of your Maps API Implementation if you
>   do so temporarily, securely, and in a
>   manner that does not permit use of the
>   Content outside of the Service; and
>   (ii) any content identifier or key
>   that the Maps APIs Documentation
>   specifically permits you to store. For
>   example, you must not use the Content
>   to create an independent database of
>   “places.”

Comment: Sure, but let's say that there's nothing about storing etc. in the terms. Is it alright then?

Comment: In that case you should be extremely careful that you are not violating some other terms. It's easy to get caught doing something else that may be disallowed, such as creating a derivative work. Because this too may be against the TOS.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it will depend on the terms and conditions set out by the API provider. You may find though that you can run in to issues where your copy is not as up-to-date as the live version - and you will need to find a way to refresh your local copy without going over the call limits. It also won't necessarily solve any issues you have with call throttling with write operations which must update the master database(s).

Comment: It has to do with words and dictionaries, so I won't be in need of any newer versions or updates.